# Payment Request API in Cordova

Tags: cordova, payment-request-api

Has anyone been able to use Payment Request in a Cordova Android app?
`window.PaymentRequest()` always return "undefined" although the installed Chrome browser is updated and [the demo](https://paymentrequest.show/demo/) works great!

Example code:

```
if (window.PaymentRequest) {
    console.log("It Worked!"); // This is never called
} else {
    console.log("Opsie, no Payment Request enabled");
}
```

Note that I tested this in a freshly created Cordova project and it works great on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Payment Request API is currently prohibited to use inside WebViews which means it won't work in Cordova.

See compatibility table at the bottom on "Android WebView": https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Payment_Request_API